# html accept in mac ignores .tar.gz extension

Tags: html, macos

I need to to have a file selection that only accepts tar.gz.

so I added `accept=".tar.gz"` and everything seemed to work fine.

Then a teammate of mine complained that it doesn't work for him. and indeed it didn't..

the only difference is that he runs on mac and I am on ubuntu. we both use chrome.

to resolve this, we added `.gz` (just .gz) on the accept attribute.

has anyone seen this? is there a solution to this problem?